# Bootstrap datetimepicker calendar is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I am using bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. Here Bootstrap datetimepicker calendar is not visible outside the grid. It is hiding inside the grid. Please see the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtzxsa3e/

```js
$(function () {
    var data = [

        { rank: 1, company: 'Exxon Mobil', DatePicker: '04/04/1990 00:00', revenues: '339938.0', profits: '36130.0' },

        { rank: 2, company: 'Wal-Mart Stores', DatePicker: '05/03/2014 00:00', revenues: '315654.0', profits: '11231.0' },
 ];
     var obj = { 
        height:300,
         title: "ParamQuery Grid with JSON Data",
        scrollModel:{autoFit:true, theme:true}
    };

    obj.colModel = [

        { title: "Rank", width: 100, dataType: "integer", dataIndx: "rank" },
        { title: "Company", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "company" },
        { title: "DatePicker", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "date",editable:false, 
         render : function(){
          var date = '<div class="form-group" style="width:150px;margin-left:50px;text-align:center"><div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker123"><input type="text" value="04/05/2012 00:00" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div></div>';                                                                                                                                                                             

          return date;
        }
         },
        { title: "Revenues ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float", align: "right", dataIndx: "revenues" },
    ];   

     $('body').on('mouseover','.input-group',function() { 

     $(".input-group.date").datetimepicker();

     });    

    obj.dataModel = { data: data };   

    $("#grid_json").pqGrid(obj);
});
```

```css
td.pq-grid-cell{
    overflow:visible !important;
}
span.input-group-addon {
  width: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid_json" style="margin:100px;"></div>
```

If I click the picker, bootstrap calendar is open but it is not visible the whole calendar. I want to display the calendar outside the grid. I have given "overflow:visible" and "visibility:visible" but still it is not working. Please help me for do this.

Comment: Question (& answers) refined here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29535873/525788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `overflow:hidden;` from parent containers also.

Add this css:

```
.pq-grid, .pq-grid-center, div.pq-grid-cont, .pq-grid-cont-inner {
    overflow: visible!important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rtzxsa3e/2/

I am not supporting the use of `!important` here. You know your html code well. If you can assign more specific selector which can override the default css of grid plugin, then that will also work.

Comment: If more than 10 rows are there means, the row also visible outside. Please add some more rows and see it is not working.

Comment: That's what I said, you need to adjust the selector based on the html. You can customise the selector according to the html structure