# Datetimepicker calendar is not open in correct position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I am using Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker in paramquery grid. From starting I have faced one problem, If I open datetimepicker, the calendar is hiding inside the grid. When I given the css condition

```css
.dropdown-menu {
position: fixed;
}
```

it is working. The calendar is visible clearly but it is not open in a correct place. After given "position:fixed", If I click picker icon the calendar is open in right-top of the grid or right-bottom of the grid. It is not open in an exact place. How can I resolve this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f2zc.png]

Answer (score 1):

Try using widgetParent option from Datepicker
`$(".input-group.date").datetimepicker({ widgetParent: 'body'});`

Now you can adjust positioning, widgetParent option allow you to display the widget in any container in the page.

Comment: Check this fiddle. Calendar is not visible ouside the gird.

Comment: If I click 5th row calendar I can't able to select time.

Comment: No, its not working. If I give this line, even calendar also not open.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem where my date element in a table cell clipped the widget. I could not use my date element as the widget's DOM parent, but I still wanted to use it as a visual positioning.

I've submitted a PR with code to handle this.
I've added a new option: forceElementPosition. It allows DOM parenting by
widgetParent, but positioning next to the input element.

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/1647

Comment: You nailed it - this is the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your `overflow:hidden`

```
.pq-grid td.pq-grid-cell{overflow:hidden}
```

Replace this:-

```
.pq-grid td.pq-grid-cell{overflow:visible}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rtzxsa3e/7/)

Comment: If I give "position:absolute", the calendar is hiding inside the grid.

Comment: See this fiddle. Calendar is not visible outside.

Comment: I am really Sorry. If I give "overflow:visible" for cell it is visible only outside the cell. But my requirement is, calendar will visible outside the grid also.

Comment: Please open the 5th row's calendar. Here I can't able pick time. The calendar is hiding. This is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74916/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-maddy).